# Not understanding error: "local variable 'computer_total' referenced before assignment when it is not? (I could be wrong)

Tags: python, blackjack

Excuse my syntax or communication I am new to stackoverflow. I am building the below code and I am getting an error that states the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 58, in 
> add_total_c()
> File "main.py", line 43, in add_total_c
> computer_total += computers_card[total_c]
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'computer_total' referenced before assignment

I understand that it means I am trying to reference a variable before its being called out.  but that doesn't make sense to me because **computer_total** is being referenced after the variable has been set in memory. I have bold specific code below for visual. In my head I feel that having the variables listed above first allows the below code to be referenced. but for some reason when calling the function it feels the variable doesn't exist?

please let me know what you think and how to solve. I prefer examples if available.

```
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
computers_card = []
user_card = []
computer_total = 0 # Here
user_total = 0

def deal_computer():
  for c_card in range (1, 3):
    computers_card.append(cards[random.randint(0, len(cards))])

def deal_user():
  for u_card in range (1, 3):
    user_card.append(cards[random.randint(0, len(cards))])

def initial_cards():
  deal_computer()
  deal_user()

def add_total_c():
  for total_c in range(0,len(computers_card)):
    computer_total += computers_card[total_c] # <--

def add_total_u():
  for total_u in range(0, len(user_card)):
    user_total += user_card[total_u]

  
print(f"Your cards: {user_card}")
print(f"Computer's first cards: {computers_card}")

initial_cards()

choice = input("Type 'y' for another card or 'n' to stand with your current cards")

if choice == "n":
  add_total_c()
  add_total_u()

  stand = True
  while stand:
    if computer_total > 17 and computer_total < 21:
      if user_total > computer_total:
        print("You Won!")
        stand = False
      else:
        print("you lose!")
        stand = False
      
    if computer_total < 17:
      computers_card.append(cards[random.randint(0, len(cards))])
      add_total_c()
      if computer_total > 21:
        print("Computer Bust")
```

I have tried to placed the variables inside the functions so that the reference is available when that function code is needed.  unfortunately that creates problems when I later have to reference that code again.

Comment: Please, **do not** use Markdown syntax in code like this, use native code comments.

Comment: This would be tidier if wrapped up into a `class` instead of having all these global variables. You can't just "place variables inside the functions", they need to be shared if you're using this style of code.

Comment: @tadman by native comments are you saying to use the #comment?

Comment: Like I've done in an edit, yes. A comment appropriate for the language used.

Comment: @tadman I don't think I have learned class yet, I'll look up python docs for reference is it the same as a function or dictionary?

Comment: It's a way of *encapsulating* all those variables you need inside a tidy package, and it gives you a way of creating as many of these things as you need without any conflict between different instances of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the *computer_total* variable is defined outside the *add_total_c()* function, but when you try to modify it inside the function, Python considers it a local variable within the function's scope. To solve this, you need to explicitly tell Python to use the global variable *computer_total* instead of creating a new local one.

You can modify and use *global* keyword like this:

```
def add_total_c():
     global computer_total  # Use the global computer_total variable
     for total_c in range(len(computers_card)):
        computer_total += computers_card[total_c]
```

Comment: Technically correct, but I'd argue leaning on `global` is a sign you've done something wrong and a case for refactoring.

Comment: @tadman I don't rely on global too but as he mentioned he haven't learned classes and it would be good to know about global as well. Although using class and creating properties should be an idea approach.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm just pointing out that this *should* set off alarm bells, but that's something people will learn in time. I'd rather people don't get real cozy with leaning on `global`, is all.

Comment: @tadman what would be a better option then global.  I feel that was the perfect answer I needed? I am asking so that I can better understand.

Comment: @tadman it seems as a beginner I don't understand the issues that global can cause later on.  Can you reference a good Class document I can read on?

Comment: @NavkarJain Thank you very much for your help!  I think this helps greatly.  Now to find another barrier and spend hours trying to fix it!

Comment: This "fixes" the problem but creates additional problems. A more comprehensive solution is to adapt your code to be inside a `class` where these functions take a `self` argument. Lots of examples out there on how to do that, and what it means is your globals become properties, which is way easier to test and maintain.

Comment: There are tons of great Python books and reference material, but you'll need *some* to learn effectively. Personally I used the [O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-python-5th/9781449355722/) book, but that's not to say it's necessarily the best. At the time I was learning there were far fewer options.

Comment: `global` is a known problem in any programming language for many reasons: Inadvertently re-using a variable in two completely different situations, creating globals that are never used leading to clutter, making it hard to find out where these variables are defined, and most importantly, it allows having more than one instance at a time without conflict. This code can't deal with more than one run simultaneously.